# Outlook Addin - Need to get data of email opened/read UI-Less implimentation

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins

How to fetch details of email/item opened/read in outlook with UI-Less addin. I tried ItemChanged event but that is working only with Pinneable TaskPane is there any alternative of ItemChanged without UI.

[LaunchEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch) are there for UI-Less implementation but not seen any event for mail/item opened/read.

Using ReactJS for addin

Comment: Can you explain your scenario a little more? What details are you trying to fetch?

Comment: on mail read need to track sender of email on organization level

Answer (score 0):

There is no mail open or read activation events for web add-ins. You can read about available activation rules in manifest files in the [Activation rules for contextual Outlook add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/activation-rules) article.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no support for Outlook add-ins to run without user interaction in the read scenario.

To achieve your requirement to capture information on mail read, you can consider a backend service discussed in this post [Outlook add-in -> Context add-in Manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67812408/outlook-add-in-context-add-in-manifest)